# change state using setstate

Tags: reactjs, setstate

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   option:[
      {first:1,id:1}
      {first:2,id:2},
     {first:3,id:3}
]
}
```

How can I change the value of option state second element which is first:2 through setstate.
Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

Update an object in an array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) without mutating the state.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  option: prevState.option.map(op => ( op.first == 2 ? { ...op, first:4 } : op ))
}));
```

This updates `first:2` to `first:4`.